# div is initially collapsed even after using 'collapse in' class for it

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

In the below code the division #content1 is initially being collapsed even after using "collapse in" class. What should I do to show the content of Column1 initially? 
Note: I don't want to use any javascript function to handle this task

```html
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
         <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
         </head>
         <body>
        
         <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <h1> <a href="#content1" data-toggle="collapse"> Column1 </a></h1> 
            <div id="content1" class="collapse in">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi malesuada iaculis hendrerit. Integer volutpat turpis id dui imperdiet fermentum. Vestibulum id augue diam. Donec efficitur sagittis ex eget malesuada. In elementum eu odio id viverra. Vivamus massa odio, scelerisque pharetra orci et, dignissim ullamcorper justo. Quisque id pretium purus, eget iaculis purus.
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <a href="#content2" data-toggle="collapse"><h1> Column2 </h1> </a>
            <div id="content2" class="collapse">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi malesuada iaculis hendrerit. Integer volutpat turpis id dui imperdiet fermentum. Vestibulum id augue diam. Donec efficitur sagittis ex eget malesuada. In elementum eu odio id viverra. Vivamus massa odio, scelerisque pharetra orci et, dignissim ullamcorper justo. Quisque id pretium purus, eget iaculis purus.
        
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <a href="#content3" data-toggle="collapse"><h1> Column3 </h1> </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="content3">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi malesuada iaculis hendrerit. Integer volutpat turpis id dui imperdiet fermentum. Vestibulum id augue diam. Donec efficitur sagittis ex eget malesuada. In elementum eu odio id viverra. Vivamus massa odio, scelerisque pharetra orci et, dignissim ullamcorper justo. Quisque id pretium purus, eget iaculis purus.
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.in` was used in bootstrap 3 (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse). In bootstrap 4 it's now `.show` (https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#example).

So you need to add the class `.show` to the div:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </head>
        <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <h1> <a href="#content1" data-toggle="collapse"> Column1 </a></h1> 
                    <div id="content1" class="collapse in **show**">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi malesuada iaculis hendrerit. Integer volutpat turpis id dui imperdiet fermentum. Vestibulum id augue diam. Donec efficitur sagittis ex eget malesuada. In elementum eu odio id viverra. Vivamus massa odio, scelerisque pharetra orci et, dignissim ullamcorper justo. Quisque id pretium purus, eget iaculis purus.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                    <a href="#content2" data-toggle="collapse"><h1> Column2 </h1> </a>
                    <div id="content2" class="collapse">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi malesuada iaculis hendrerit. Integer volutpat turpis id dui imperdiet fermentum. Vestibulum id augue diam. Donec efficitur sagittis ex eget malesuada. In elementum eu odio id viverra. Vivamus massa odio, scelerisque pharetra orci et, dignissim ullamcorper justo. Quisque id pretium purus, eget iaculis purus.

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <a href="#content3" data-toggle="collapse"><h1> Column3 </h1> </a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="content3">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi malesuada iaculis hendrerit. Integer volutpat turpis id dui imperdiet fermentum. Vestibulum id augue diam. Donec efficitur sagittis ex eget malesuada. In elementum eu odio id viverra. Vivamus massa odio, scelerisque pharetra orci et, dignissim ullamcorper justo. Quisque id pretium purus, eget iaculis purus.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it would be of great help if you could let me know why the class 'collapse in' is not handling the task of showing the div initially

Comment: `.in` was used in bootstrap 3 (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse). In bootstrap 4 it's now `.show` (https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/collapse/#example).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification